# WFLYJCA0041: Failed to load module for driver [com.oracle]

Tags: oracle, jboss7.x, jndi

> I am using jdk 8 and the jboss 7.4.0 trying to connect oracle database
> through jndi in jboss. but am not able to connect and showing the
> below error. can someone help me on this. i have tried with ojdbc6.jar
> to till ojdbc14.jar still i can see the same errors.
>
> ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot
> Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
> ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
> ("data-source" => "IndigoDS") ]) - failure description: {
> "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.oracleDriver"],
> "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
> "org.wildfly.data-source.IndigoDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.oracleDriver]",
> "jboss.driver-demander.java:/IndigoDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.oracleDriver]"
> ] } 12:54:38,531 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot
> Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
> ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
> ("data-source" => "IndigoDS") ]) - failure description: {
> "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
> "jboss.jdbc-driver.oracleDriver",
> "jboss.jdbc-driver.oracleDriver"
> ],
> "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
> "org.wildfly.data-source.IndigoDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.oracleDriver]",
> "jboss.driver-demander.java:/IndigoDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.oracleDriver]",
> "org.wildfly.data-source.IndigoDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.oracleDriver]"
> ] }
>
> module.xml:
> ------------
>
> Directory  structure of module is :
> C:\jboss7.4.0\modules\system\layers\base\com\oracle\main : here I have
> placed modulee.xml and ojdbc11.jar as well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format the code using `\`\`\`` (for a code block) on a new line before the code and not `>` (for a quote).